# remove html tags from a string but restore \n

Tags: android, html

In my news application, I get the data from JSON which i need to display in the TextView.
But the data content that comes are mixed up with html tags.
I tried removing the html tags from the string but got some problems.

This is the String i have:

```
String testString = "<a href=\"#"><img src=\"xyz.jpg" width=\"196\" height=\"300\" /></a>Residents of Chisapani bazaar in the south of Khotang district have been living in darkness for the past three years.\r\n\r\nThe power house of Dobhane river Hydropower Project was damaged in a landslide three years ago.\r\n\r\n Source:ABCD";
```

I need to show this String in the TextView excluding the html tags. Thus is what I have done.

```
textbox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
textbox.setText(Html.fromHtml(testString).toString());
```

On doing so, even the \n (newline) part was omitted which turned the whole text into a single block removing the paragraphs. But this is not preffered. I need the text which is a news content to be well-paragraphed.

Can there be any way which can remove just the tags like `<a>` or `<img>` but restore \n.

Comment: Have you tried converting occurences of `\r\n` to `<br />`? [first SO result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337948/html-fromhtmlstring-linebreak-problem), [second SO result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625330/html-fromhtml-line-breaks-disappearing) for "Html.fromHtml newline"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stripping HTML tags in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832620/stripping-html-tags-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
           tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(testString.replace("\n", "<br/>")));
```

This will create new line at each "\n".
But It can cause problem when your data itself contains \n any how...